# Sort nested array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
let arr = [{
  name: 'Apple',
  trades: [{
    date: '2017.01.01',
    volume: 100
  }, {
    date: '1995.02.01',
    volume: 150
  }, {
    date: '2008.01.01',
    volume: 250
  }]
}]
```

Hello, I googled many documents for sorting nested object in JavaScript, but I couldn't find the way of my case and I struggled so many hours so I want to ask to how can I sort above array of objects.

What I expected result is sort array of object by `trades.date` like this

```
sortedArray = [{
  name: 'Apple',
  trades: [{
    date: '2017.01.01',
    volume: 100
  }, {
    date: '2008.01.01',
    volume: 250
  }, {
    date: '1995.02.01',
    volume: 150
  }]
}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you done so far to solve the problem?

Comment: @Lalit What would be the sort criteria for the output if it was sorted by the volume? O.o

Comment: Hi @Juntae, imagine you don't have access to Google, what would be your first step ?

Comment: @leaf what do u want to say?

Comment: @MinarMnr Oops sorry I updated my question Thanks

Comment: I mean, could you tell us if you have any clue to solve this problem ? Would you use a loop ? A JavaScript function ? Do you know how to manipulate arrays in JavaScript ? Please edit your question, provide more details in order for us to help better :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
arr[0].trades.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date));
});
```

You can use the array's sort method for achieving this. If you want to sort in the reverse order then just swap a and b in the return code.

Answer (score 2):

Read about `array.sort()` and `datetime` in Javascript.

```js
let arr = [{
  name: 'Apple',
  trades: [{
    date: '2017.01.01',
    volume: 100
  }, {
    date: '1995.02.01',
    volume: 150
  }, {
    date: '2008.01.01',
    volume: 250
  }]
}]

console.log(arr[0].trades.sort((tradeA, tradeB)=>{
 return (new Date(tradeA.date) - new Date(tradeB.date)) * (-1)
    // or return (new Date(tradeB.date) - new Date(tradeA.date))
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

First in your array, date needs to be a string. You can than use arrays.sort with a function which returns the result

```js
let arr = [
        {
          name : 'Apple',
          trades : [
           {date : "2017.01.01",
            volume : 100
           },
           {date : "1995.02.01",
            volume : 150
           },
           {date : "2008.01.01",
            volume : 250
           }
         ]
       }
    ]

    function compare(a,b) {
        var dateA = new Date(a.date);
      var dateB = new Date(b.date);
      if (dateA > dateB)
        return -1;
      if (dateA < dateB)
        return 1;
      return 0;
    }

    arr[0].trades.sort(compare);
    console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your date format, dot is not an iso delimiter.

```
let toArr = (aDate) => aDate.split('.')
let toDate = ([year, month, day]) => new Date(year, month - 1, day)
let compareTrades = (a, b) => toDate(toArr(a.date)) - toDate(toArr(b.date))

let arr = [{
    name: 'Apple',
    trades: [{
      date: '2017.01.01',
      volume: 100
    }, {
      date: '1995.02.01',
      volume: 150
    }, {
      date: '2008.01.01',
      volume: 250
    }]
}]

arr[0].trades.sort(compareTrades)
console.log(arr[0])
```