# Need to sort object based on value of nested object in Typescript / Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting

I am working to make an Angular 9 app on covid-19 cases where I want to sort my objects based on value of nested objects.

Here is my data I want to sort my statewise object alphabetically on basis of value of field s `tate:kerela ,state:haryana ;`

```
{
  "history": [
    {
      "day": "2020-03-14",
      "total": {
        "confirmed": 84
      },
      "statewise": [
        {
          "state": "Kerala",
          "confirmed": 19
        },
        {
          "state": "Assam",
          "confirmed": 14
        }
      ]
    },


    {
      "day": "2020-03-15",
      "total": {
        "confirmed": 104
      },
      "statewise": [
        {
          "state": "Kerala",
          "confirmed": 119
        },
        {
          "state": "Assam",
          "confirmed": 114
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

so after sorting I want my data like

**SOrted Data**

```
{
  "history": [
    {
      "day": "2020-03-14",
      "total": {
        "confirmed": 84
      },
      "statewise": [
        {
          "state": "Assam",
          "confirmed": 14
        },
        {
          "state": "Kerala",
          "confirmed": 19
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "day": "2020-03-15",
      "total": {
        "confirmed": 104
      },
      "statewise": [
        {
          "state": "Assam",
          "confirmed": 114
        },
        {
          "state": "Kerala",
          "confirmed": 119
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The link to my API data is here API data [API data link](https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/unofficial/covid19india.org/statewise/history). I have been trying for two days I have tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545956/sort-nested-array-of-object-in-javascript/47546187) but still not getting how should I proceed. Any help will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will help:

```
this.postService.getDetails().subscribe(
  response => {
    let sortedData= response.data.history
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
      }); //Sort based on date

      sortedData.forEach(item=>item.statewise.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.state < b.state) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a.state > b.state) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      })); //sort state wise in alphabetical order

    console.log(sortedData);
    this.loading = false;
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
    this.loading = false;
  }
);
```

Sample demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-operators-examples?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstackoverflow%2Fmerge-map-error%2Fmerge-map-error.component.ts

https://angular-rxjs-operators-examples.stackblitz.io/stackoverflow

Look the console for sorted data.

Comment: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)  getting error where you have sorted date @Anoop

Comment: Is working for me... I tried in stackblitz. Can you open the link - https://angular-rxjs-operators-examples.stackblitz.io/stackoverflow and check?

Comment: Thank you for the update. If found working please click the up button as well. :)

Comment: I cant because I dont have reutation of 15+ it was my seocnd question nly

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `sort` prototype of array.

```js
let records = {
  "history": [
    {
      "day": "2020-03-14",
      "total": {
        "confirmed": 84
      },
      "statewise": [
        {
          "state": "Kerala",
          "confirmed": 19
        },
        {
          "state": "Assam",
          "confirmed": 14
        }
      ]
    },


    {
      "day": "2020-03-15",
      "total": {
        "confirmed": 104
      },
      "statewise": [
        {
          "state": "Kerala",
          "confirmed": 119
        },
        {
          "state": "Assam",
          "confirmed": 114
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const res = {history: []};

res.history = records.history.map(history => {
 history.statewise.sort((a, b) => a.state < b.state ? -1 : 1);
    return history;
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    min-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'statewise' of undefined it is giving this error  @Sajeeb

Comment: Hm WHat could go worng I am doing same in typescript

Comment: Code you share your .ts code? At my end its working